# Why does this umlaut char consists of two chars, so i have to use backspace twice?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have seen one Problem in Firefox, where an Umlaut looks disrupted (one blank space behind, or the dots are beside the char). If I'm trying to delete this umlaut, you can see in the following gif that I have to use backspace twice to remove the char. First it removes the dots, then the "u" char.

I'm asking this question because I wan't to figure out how this happens. I've seen this problem with text which was copied from an PDF file and then is save in an wysiwyg editor. After saving, the frontend shows these "damaged" umlauts.

I've seen this happen on many different web pages from customers. So it would be nice to "trigger" this char via CSS to add some red color or something else to show the "bad" umlauts. :)

Has someone seen something like that before?

[image: Umlaut Problem]

And here in Sublime:

[image]

Comment: Unicode provides a Combining Diaeresis “character”, that can be combined with a “normal” letter, to have it become an umlaut. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)#Character_encodings

Comment: @CBroe That sounds right. Do you have an idea how i can "target" them with css or javascript, to highlight them?

Comment: With CSS you can not directly format characters at arbitrary positions, so you would have to wrap them in an additional HTML element first. Using JavaScript, that could possibly work using a little regular expression, that looks for the Combining Diaeresis character plus any character before it, and groups those into an additional span or something ...

Comment: @CBroe would you like to enter an "answer"? I would like to accept it than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode provides a Combining Diaeresis “character”, that can be combined with a “normal” letter, to have it become an umlaut.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)#Character_encodings

> So it would be nice to "trigger" this char via CSS to add some red color or something else to show the "bad" umlauts.

With CSS you can not directly format characters at arbitrary positions, so you would have to wrap them in an additional HTML element first.

Using JavaScript, that could possibly work using a little regular expression, that looks for the Combining Diaeresis character plus any character before it, and groups those into an additional span or something.